# How do I check if a chef databag has correct syntax within a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, databags

Say that the databag I am using is missing a bracket or comma, is there a way to check that within a script?

Comment: `JSON.parse` and see if it succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its not a direct answer you are expecting , Let me say how I validate the data bags.

I always start with creating a json file which I will use for populating data bag. Let me outline the step I follow and it always worked for me.

1. Create data bag

   `knife data bag create example1`
2. Create json file: `/tmp/example1_data.json`:

   `{ "id": "id1", "name": "example1" }`
3. Validate the json file 
    `python -mjson.tool /tmp/example1_data.json`

This will tell you whether the json file is validate or not

4 . populate data bag items

`knife data bag from file example1 /tmp/example1.json`